# How to name short phrases played to make "frame" for e.g. vocal solo?

Tags: terminology

How to name short phrases played to make "frame" for vocal solo?

For example "Cambio Dolor" (original, performed by Natalia Oreiro) song, there are two guitars playing in verse: rythm & the phrases I am talking about. How to name them?

I guess it is not the bridge, is it? The bridge should be between solid parts e.g.: verse and chorus, right?

Comment: yes, bridge would be wrong. it is what you said: rather between chorus and verse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic arranging technique.  Someone has the tune, someone else fills in the gap.  IN this song sometimes it's the brass, sometimes a guitar.

'Fills'.  'Fill-ins'. [Fill (music) wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fill_(music))

Comment: fill ins I have been thinking of
vote up

Answer (score 0):

There was a  similar question the other day about the piano playing around the melody between the phrases of the vocal soloist:

I'd name this **"paraphrasing".**
look up wiki *paraphrase* `wiki English` or **paraphrase musik**  `wiki de`

I didn't find a link in English *paraphrase music*

and I don't know whether there exists another term than **soloing.**

**Paraphrasing Defined**
We've all watched television shows or heard news stories we wanted to tell others about. We may have told our friends, our family, or our coworkers about what happened, how it happened, and why it happened. We recounted the storyline, the main characters, the events, and important points using our own words. This is paraphrasing - using your own words to express someone else's message or ideas. In a paraphrase, the ideas and meaning of the original source must be maintained; the main ideas need to come through, but the wording has to be your own.

Comment: What I've found about "paraphrase music" it is a cover-like music: https://musicterms.artopium.com/p/Paraphrase.htm

Comment: "This is paraphrasing - using your own words to express someone else's message or ideas. In a paraphrase, the ideas and meaning of the original source must be maintained; the main ideas need to come through, but the wording has to be your own."

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli - That quote you used would fit all the paraphrases I have listened to, such as Liszt's paraphrases of others' works and Gottschalk's "The Union". Note that none of them have the original playing at the same time.

Comment: that's why I say "paraphrasing" (en paranthèse).

the paraphrases in music is what you describe, as well as a bridge is somewhat different. It is not the first time that a word has been adapted for something new or different. we two are most competent to do this. 

but this "thing" here has already been used by Bach. we will look up and find out  what it has been called there. ;)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8g-9zXv1O8

as I mentioned Bach I was just thinking of this!
look up 6:15

Comment: the  Solo-Aria starts  at 7:13. the oboe is not only echoing, it is not only filling, it is "paraphrasing". I listen to sometimes to an music hour in the radio, where they discuss 5 recordings of the same music composition. I'm pretty sure they use there the term paraphrasing, which I've known from psychology and psychiatric counseling techniques (Carl Rogers). and it fits quite well for what is asked here.